# "IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system" error in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, ioerror

I have a function in Flask that does some web scraping and puts the content in a HTML file.

```
@app.route('/something')
def something():
    web_scraping()
    return render_template('myFile.html')
```

The function `web_scraping` outputs some HTML code to `myFile.html` and works great when I run it locally, but when I put it on Google App Engine, I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'templates/myFile.html'
```

Answer (score 3):

[You cannot write to the file system](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage)

> Why can't I write to this file?
>
> Writing to local files is not supported in App Engine due to the
>   distributed nature of your application. Instead, data which must be
>   persisted should be stored in the distributed datastore. For more
>   information see the documentation on the runtime sandbox

However, you still can writing files:

> In App Engine, the local filesystem that your application is deployed
>   to is not writeable. This behavior ensures the security and
>   scalability of your application.
>
> However, if the application needs to write and read files at runtime,
>   App Engine provides a built-in Google Cloud Storage stream wrapper
>   that allows you to use many of the standard PHP filesystem functions
>   to read and write files in an App Engine PHP app.

Comment: The `/tmp` solution works like a charm. The most important thing to do is to use the `os.remove` function to remove the file as soon as the job is done.(or the equivalent of it in your language.)

Comment: Just use your regular cloud file library and write something like 

`fhandler.write("\tmp\{}".format(<your_file_name>))`

and then erase all the files and the directory completely.

check this link: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-temp-files

@DarrenZou