# Read-only file system: '/dev/null' while running google-cloud-sdk project

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am trying to run an existing project of gcloud. This project was working fine on my previous laptop. I copied the exact same SDK and project to my new laptop but not working anymore.

Here is the error I am facing:

```
dev_appserver.py app_impel.yaml --port=9099 --datastore_path=/home/rumi/Documents/impel/impel_eyevestor_ayaz --threadsafe_override=false --max_module_instances=1 --enable_console --enable_host_checking=false
INFO     2020-10-06 05:59:57,659 devappserver2.py:105] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2020-10-06 05:59:57,877 simple_search_stub.py:1196] Could not read search indexes from /tmp/appengine.impel-eyevestor.rumi/search_indexes
INFO     2020-10-06 05:59:57,879 api_server.py:265] Starting API server at: http://localhost:44015
INFO     2020-10-06 05:59:59,617 dispatcher.py:255] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:9099
INFO     2020-10-06 05:59:59,619 admin_server.py:152] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2020-10-06 06:00:43,739 module.py:835] default: "GET /swagger.json HTTP/1.1" 304 -
WARNING  2020-10-06 06:00:43,928 sandbox.py:1086] The module _winreg is whitelisted for local dev only. If your application relies on _winreg, it is likely that it will not function properly in production.
WARNING  2020-10-06 06:00:43,988 sandbox.py:1086] The module _ctypes is whitelisted for local dev only. If your application relies on _ctypes, it is likely that it will not function properly in production.
ERROR    2020-10-06 06:00:44,513 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rumi/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/rumi/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/rumi/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/rumi/Desktop/eye_env/eyevestor-api-server-v1/api_server/api_server.py", line 100, in <module>
    import eyevestor.security.decorators
  File "/home/rumi/Desktop/eye_env/eyevestor-api-server-v1/api_server/eyevestor/security/decorators.py", line 13, in <module>
    from jose import jwt
  File "/home/rumi/Desktop/eye_env/eyevestor-api-server-v1/api_server/lib/jose/jwt.py", line 11, in <module>
    from jose import jws
  File "/home/rumi/Desktop/eye_env/eyevestor-api-server-v1/api_server/lib/jose/jws.py", line 8, in <module>
    from jose import jwk
  File "/home/rumi/Desktop/eye_env/eyevestor-api-server-v1/api_server/lib/jose/jwk.py", line 13, in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
  File "/home/rumi/Desktop/eye_env/eyevestor-api-server-v1/api_server/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 42, in <module>
    from Crypto.Math.Numbers import Integer
  File "/home/rumi/Desktop/eye_env/eyevestor-api-server-v1/api_server/lib/Crypto/Math/Numbers.py", line 42, in <module>
    from Crypto.Math._Numbers_gmp import Integer
  File "/home/rumi/Desktop/eye_env/eyevestor-api-server-v1/api_server/lib/Crypto/Math/_Numbers_gmp.py", line 93, in <module>
    lib = load_lib("gmp", gmp_defs)
  File "/home/rumi/Desktop/eye_env/eyevestor-api-server-v1/api_server/lib/Crypto/Util/_raw_api.py", line 132, in load_lib
    full_name = find_library(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/util.py", line 285, in find_library
    return _findSoname_ldconfig(name) or _get_soname(_findLib_gcc(name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/util.py", line 269, in _findSoname_ldconfig
    null = open(os.devnull, 'wb')
  File "/home/rumi/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/stubs.py", line 278, in __init__
    raise IOError(errno.EROFS, 'Read-only file system', filename)
IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/dev/null'
INFO     2020-10-06 06:00:44,524 module.py:835] default: "GET /api/v1/users/current HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Also tried this steps here [steps](https://rmosolgo.github.io/blog/2013/08/05/enable-filesystem-writes-in-gae-dev-appserver/) but then facing another error like `file not accessible /dev/null`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since your initial error is

> IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system:

you may try removing ***logging.conf*** all together or remove the handler that writes to a file (in case your application has a write operation) as App Engine does not support any write operations to the file system (among other restrictions).

While investigating this error, I came across few posts which could assist you in resolving this error:

- [Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/g/web2py/c/VNx1pCgAEZA)
- StackOverflow posts:

  - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016011/ioerror-errno-30-read-only-file-system-geckodriver-log)
  - [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975208/ioerror-errno-30-read-only-file-system-error-in-google-app-engine)

I hope this information helps.

Comment: How to remove logging.conf and is it safe to remove it?

Comment: The [logging.config](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html) file in Python is configuring the logging module. It is stated that the use is optional, thus I assume it is safe to remove it. [Here](https://thejimmyg.github.io/pylonsbook/en/1.1/logging.html#introducing-logging-configuration) is some sdditional information on Logging Configuration that you might find helpful.